# How to disrupt WiFi communication between two esp's?

Tags: communication

I have 1 ESP01S transmitter and a NODEMCU12E receiver that communicate through my home router using the same IP through client.connect(server, 80);

The application is not professional at all, but the fragility of this communication bothers me. So I ask:

If I have a third ESP on hand, if it is within range of my WiFi router and knows the IP through which my two TX RX ESPs communicate, can I somehow interrupt communication between them?

NOTE: Communication occurs successfully only if the TX sends a String to the RX. Ex: 123456789. The third ESP does not have this information. It only has the IP.

Understand, it's just curiosity. My curiosity.

Thanks.

In the beginning, I used communication with TX-RX 433Mhz modules with code learning, like garage door key fobs, and I saw that it was enough to have a cloning key fob or an espRX to discover the code.

My question now is in communication as I described above.